# Using Laravel eloquent relationship (One to Many) returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

when Im using Laravel eloquent - relationships (One To Many) the result is NULL.
I have setted up data in "work_hour" table, where "workers_id" has value 2 and there is row in "workers" table with id=2 
I followed the documentation "[Laravel relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many)"

My schema looks like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('work_hour', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('worked_hour');

            $table->time('worked_from');
            $table->time('worked_to');
            $table->integer('workers_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('workers_id')->references('id')->on('workers');
            $table->integer('workday_id');
            $table->integer('offer_id');
        });
    }
```

PS: columns workday_id, offer_id arent set foreign,yet!

Models are looks like this:

```
class Worker extends Eloquent{

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name'];

}

class Workhour extends Eloquent{

    protected $table    = 'work_hour';

    public function worker(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Worker','workers_id');
    }

}
```

Controller
PS: I searched over the same issue on SO, I tried some opinion, then I commented them out

```
class WorkerController extends BaseController {
    protected $table    = 'workers';
....
    public function show($id){
        $worker     = Worker::find($id);

    //  $workhour   = Workhour::where('workers_id','=',$worker->id)->get(); 
    // casting the result: works $workhour->toArray()

    //  $workhour   = Worker::find($id)->with('workhour')->get(); 
    //Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::workhour()

    //  $workhour   = Worker::with('workhour')->where('id',2)->get(); 
    //Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::workhour()

    $workhour   = Worker::find($id)->workhour; 
    // null

        dd($workhour);
        return View::make('worker.show',['worker' => $worker,'workhour'=>$workhour]);
    }

    public function workhour(){
      return $this->hasMany('Workhour','workers_id');
    }


}
```

Im calling the "show.blade.php" with ".../public/worker/2" (Laravel 4)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the Eloquent relationship (`workhour()` method and the table name) defined in your controller?

Comment: It returns `null` because there is no relation defined on the `Worker` model.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ thank you, you have right, I have added the workhour() function into the controller not in the model, thank you! Now it works perfectly, ... you should write answer for acceptation

Comment: @kajetons beacuse the table name is "workers" but the model is "Worker"

Comment: I meant why is it in the controller instead of your Eloquent model. Anyway, it should be solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add the relation to the Model not Controller:

```
class Worker extends Eloquent{

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name'];

    public function workhour(){
      return $this->hasMany('Workhour','workers_id');
    }
}
```